# wals chapter 50 regarding german language

Tags: syntax, linguistic-typology, cases, german

Regarding asymmetrical case marking in German referring WALS chapter 50, I understand the asymmetry in German (*ich* : I; *mich* : me; *mir* : to me; *er* : he; *ihm* : to him; *ihn* : him, etc.) but the value is coded as syncretism in relevant NP types.

Can someone show me syncretism in NP types? I have doubts what I should consider as NP types.

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with the examples "ich : I mich : me mir : to me, er he, ihm to him, ihn him"? What more do you want?

Comment: can you please explain the syncretism in them? that is what I cannot explain well... thanks!

Comment: Do you mean, what historical fact explains why syncretism exists in German? You might start by saying what *you* think syncretism refers to. The article doesn't actually give any German examples, so you should explain what you *think* is an example, and why you think that.